# Python Chat Room "ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to make a chat room that works on localhost with `threading` and `socket`. Here is the code:

```py
# Server side

import threading
import socket

host = 'localhost'
port = 11298
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host, port))
server.listen()
clients = []
nicks = []
def broadcast(msg):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(msg)

def handle(client):
    while True:
        try:
            msg = client.recv(1024)
            broadcast(msg)
        except:
            index = clients.index(client)
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
            nick = nicks[index]
            broadcast(f'{nick} has left.'.encode('utf-8'))
            nicks.remove(nick)
            break

def recv():
    while True:
        print('The chat room is online ...')
        client, address = server.accept()
        print(f'You are connected to {str(address)}')
        client.send('nick'.encode('utf-8'))
        nick = client.recv(1024)
        nicks.append(nick)
        clients.append(client)
        broadcast(f'{nick} has joined.'.encode('utf-8'))
        client.send('You have been connected!'.encode('utf-8'))
        thread = threading.Thread(target = handle(), args = (client))
        thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    recv()
```

```py
# Client side

import threading
import socket

nick = input('Choose a nickname: ')
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('localhost', 11298))

def cl_recv():
    while True:
        try:
            msg = client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            if msg == 'nick':
                client.send(nick.encode('utf-8'))
            else:
                print(msg)
        except:
            print("Something went wrong! Bummer.")
            client.close()
            break

def cl_send():
    while True:
        msg = f'{nick}: {input("")}'
        client.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))

receive_th = threading.Thread(target = cl_recv)
receive_th.start
```

Whenever I run the code (one cmd window for the server and two for the clients to test it out) it gives me this error:

```sh
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I'm guessing it's a problem with the client closing the server, but I'm using `client.connect`. I've looked at the code multiple times and can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by the two sides of the connection disagreeing over whether the connection timed out or not during a keepalive. (Your code tries to reused the connection just as the server is closing it because it has been idle for too long.) You should basically just retry the operation over a new connection.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I don't really understand what you mean by "retry the operation over a new connection".